# How can I increase the speed of my download manager program?

Tags: performance, download, download-manager, http-1.1

I am writing a download manager program.And In my program the urls are downloaded in a normal speed.How can I increase the speed of the downloads?Is it about HTTP 1.1 or is there an algorithm to do this job?

Answer (score 1):

There is an algorithm used in a lot of download managers. It cuts the file in parts and download them at the same time - it speeds up downloading when the file server limits download speed for single user per file to avoid excessive traffic. You have to keep in mind that not all servers will allow that.